# parsing multi nested json with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

I have to parse the json file into text file, Sample json file as below,

> ```
> {
>   "link":"https://xxx.nt",
>   "liveChannels":[
>                       {
>                           "name":"Sony TV",
>                           "id":1004,
>                           "link":"https://xxx.nt",
>                           "decryptionTicket":"https://xxxy.nt",
>                           "viewLevel":"Too High",
>                               "programs":
>                                   {
>                                   "totalItems":1,
>                                   "programs":[
>                                                   {
>                                                       "name":"Live or die",
>                                                       "id":1000000000,
>                                                       "catchUp":["FUN"],
>                                                       "startOver":["Again"]
>                                                   }
>                                               ]
>                               }
>                   }
>               ]
> }
> ```

I have used GSON to parse the file by creating the below java classes.

1. Channel
2. LiveChannel
3. programs
4. subprograms

Channel.java

```
public class channel 
{

    String link = null;
    ArrayList<liveChannels> liveChannels;

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public ArrayList<liveChannels> getliveChannels() {
        return liveChannels;
    }

    public void setliveChannels(ArrayList<liveChannels> liveChannels) {
        this.liveChannels = liveChannels;
    }

}
```

livechannel.java

```
public class liveChannels {

    String name = null;
    int id;
    String link = null;
    String decryptionTicket = null;
    String viewLevel = null;


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    public void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    public String getDecryptionTicket() {
        return decryptionTicket;
    }

    public void setDecryptionTicket(String decryptionTicket) {
        this.decryptionTicket = decryptionTicket;
    }

    public String getViewLevel() {
        return viewLevel;
    }

    public void setViewLevel(String viewLevel) {
        this.viewLevel = viewLevel;
    }

}
```

After this how to parse the logic from program onwards.

> "programs":
>                                     {
>                                     "totalItems":1,

program.java

```
public class programs {

    ArrayList<sub_programs> sub_programs;

    int totalItems;

    public int getTotalItems() {
        return totalItems;
    }

    public void setTotalItems(int totalItems) {
        this.totalItems = totalItems;
    }

    public ArrayList<sub_programs> getProgramsDetails() {
        return sub_programs;
    }

    public void setProgramsDetails(ArrayList<sub_programs> sub_programs) {
        this.sub_programs = sub_programs;
    }

}
```

sub_program.java

```
public class sub_programs {

    String name = null;
    int id;
    String catchUp = null;
    String startOver = null;


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCatchUp() {
        return catchUp;
    }

    public void setCatchUp(String catchUp) {
        this.catchUp = catchUp;
    }

    public String getStartOver() {
        return startOver;
    }

    public void setStartOver(String startOver) {
        this.startOver = startOver;
    }

}
```

and main look like below,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {

        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String contents = FileUtils.readFileToString(
                new File("C:/sample.json"), "UTF-8");

        channel channelHeader = gson.fromJson(contents, channel.class);

        System.out.println("Channel Information --->");

        System.out.println("Channel Link: " + channelHeader.getLink());

        ArrayList<liveChannels> liveChannels = channelHeader.getliveChannels();

        for (int i = 0; i < liveChannels.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("liveChannels Detail --->");
            liveChannels liveChannelsDetail = liveChannels.get(i);
            System.out.println("Channel Name : " + liveChannelsDetail.getName());
            System.out.println("Channel ID : " + liveChannelsDetail.getId());
            System.out.println("Channel Description Ticket: " + liveChannelsDetail.getDecryptionTicket());
            System.out.println("Channel View Level : " + liveChannelsDetail.getViewLevel());
        }

    }

}
```

Could anyone please help to get the logic to parse the program from livechannel class onwards.

As programs is not an array list , What else would be an other way around to get the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `programs` object in your `liveChannels` class.

```
public class liveChannels {

    String name = null;
    int id;
    String link = null;
    String decryptionTicket = null;
    String viewLevel = null;
    programs programs;

    public void setPrograms (programs programs) {
        this.programs = programs;
    }

    public programs getPrograms() {
        return programs;
    }

    ...
}
```

And then in your `programs` class, you will need to rename the `sub_programs` field to `programs`

```
public class programs {

    ArrayList<sub_programs> programs;

    ...
}
```

As an aside, your class naming does not follow Java standards and is considered bad practice. Your classes should be named as such:

```
Channel
LiveChannel
Program
SubProgram
```

Note that this will not affect GSON's ability to parse your documents as GSON cares more about the property name than it does the actual class name of the field.